# yield results in `finish_bundle` from a custom DoFn

Tags: apache-beam

One step of my pipeline involves fetching from an external data source and I'd like to do that in chunks (order doesn't matter). I couldn't find any class that does something similar so I've created the following:

```
class FixedSizeBatchSplitter(beam.DoFn):
  def __init__(self, size):
    self.size = size

  def start_bundle(self):
    self.current_batch = []

  def finish_bundle(self):
    if self.current_batch: 
      yield self.current_batch

  def process(self, element):
    self.current_batch.append(element)
    if len(self.current_batch) >= self.size:
      yield self.current_batch
      self.current_batch = []
```

However, when I run this pipeline, I get a `RuntimeError: Finish Bundle should only output WindowedValue type` error:

```
with beam.Pipeline() as p:
  res = (p
         | beam.Create(range(10))
         | beam.ParDo(FixedSizeBatchSplitter(3))
        )
```

Why is that? How comes that I can yield outputs in `process` but not in `finish_bundle`? By the way, if I remove `finish_bundle` the pipeline works but obviously discards the leftovers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `DoFn` may be processing elements from multiple different windows. When you're in `process()`, the "current window" is unambiguous - it's the window of the element being processed. When you're in `finish_bundle`, it's ambiguous and you need to specify the window explicitly. You need to be yielding something of the form `yield WindowedValue(something, timestamp, [window])`.

If all your data is in the global window, that makes it easier: `window` will be just `GlobalWindow()`. If you're using multiple windows, then you'll need to have 1 buffer per window; capture the window in `process()` so that you add to the proper buffer; and in `finish_bundle` emit each of them in the respective window.

Comment: thanks! what happens if I don't have a `timestamp` in my data? I'm doing a preprocessing of some data that is not the main list of events. Don't have the notion of time or windows. How does that play with Beam? (leaving the `timestamp` arg None didn't seem to be a good idea...)

Comment: You can use MIN_TIMESTAMP from apache_beam.utils.timestamp.